# Is there a way to fix this error : no match for 'operator[]' (operand types are 'empl' and 'int')

Tags: c++

Im getting homework done but i faced this problem i tried everything changing variables name, changing function ....
I looked into this problem on google still no idea how to fix this error.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<iostream>

struct empl {
    char nom;
    char pre;
    float salaire;
    double cin;
}empl;
struct empl t[50];
struct empl E;

int taille(int n)
{
    printf("saisie la taille de tableaux\n");
    scanf("%d\n", &n);
    return 0;
}

int remplire(int n, struct empl t, int i)

{
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        printf("t[%d].nom= ", i);
        scanf("%s\n", &t[i].nom);
        printf("t[%d].prenom= ", i);
        scanf("%s\n", &t[i].pre);
        printf("t[%d].salaire= ", i);
        scanf("%f\n", &t[i].salaire);
        printf("t[%d].CIN= ", i);
        scanf("%lf\n", &t[i].cin);
    }
}
int main()
{
    int i, n;
    int taille(int n),
        taille(n);
    int remplire(int n, struct empl t, int i);
    remplire(n, t, i);
}
```

Comment: C or C++?  `#include <iostream>` and `operator[]` are both C++, but you tagged the question C.  Which is it?

Comment: `char nom` is a single character not a string. I'd recommend getting a good C programming book, you can't learn by trial & error.

Comment: Don't mix apples and oranges. `stdio.h` is a C header file. `iostream` is a C++ header file. Restrict yourself to one language as the two are quite different.

Comment: sorry guys miss click its c++

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although your code is written mostly in C style, you seem to be compiling it with a C++ compiler, as it accepts `#include <iostream>` (though you do not appear to use anything from it), and it has a notion of operator overloading.  C and C++ are distinct languages, and the distinction is somewhat relevant here.

In either language, however, the code you have presented is flawed.  The problem is with the several expressions in function `remplire` that follow this pattern: `&t[i].nom`.  Absent any operator overloading (which is not available in C anyway), the `[]` operator in those expressions requires one of its operands to designate either a pointer or an array, and the other to designate an integer.  Although there is a file-scope variable `t` that is an array, inside `remplire()` that is *shadowed* by a function parameter with the same name.  Inside that function, then, `t` refers the the parameter, which is a `struct empl`, not an array or pointer (or integer).

Your compiler ought to be giving you another clue, too, where you *call* that function ...

> ```
>     remplire(n,t,i);
> ```

..., passing the global `t` as an argument. The compiler very much should complain about a type mismatch between the second argument (`t`) and the corresponding function parameter.

Perhaps what you wanted to do is simply to declare `remplire()` to accept a structure *pointer* as its second parameter:

```
int remplire(int n, struct empl *t, int i)
```

While you're at it, do remove the redundant local declaration of that function inside `main()`.  You don't need that as long as `remplire()` is defined before `main()`, and if you want to have a separate declaration of that function then it would best be placed at file scope, and probably in a header file.

Answer (score 2):

There are many issues in your code.

Starting reading a good C textbook is advised.

You probably want this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

struct empl {
  char nom[30];
  char pre[30];
  float salaire;
  double cin;
}empl;

struct empl t[50];
struct empl E;

int taille(int & n)
{
  printf("saisie la taille de tableaux\n");
  scanf("%d", &n);
  return 0;
}

void remplire(int n, struct empl *t)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
  {
    printf("t[%d].nom= ", i);
    scanf("%s", &t[i].nom);
    printf("t[%d].prenom= ", i);
    scanf("%s", &t[i].pre);
    printf("t[%d].salaire= ", i);
    scanf("%f", &t[i].salaire);
    printf("t[%d].CIN= ", i);
    scanf("%lf", &t[i].cin);
  }
}

int main()
{
  int n;
  taille(n);
  remplire(n, t);
}
```

It's still poor code and it's written mostly in C style, but it compiles and works as intended.

In C++ you'd do this totally differently.

Comment: Thanks im a beginner in c++ and im learning by my self so i face many problems
i usually google the problem and i get the solution but not this time however thank you

Answer (score 2):

First of all `iostream` is C++ header coming from standard library and will not work for C program. And now issues:

```
int taille (int n)
{
  printf("saisie la taille de tableaux\n");
  scanf("%d\n",&n);
  return 0;
}
```

This function is called with an input parameter - that means you can pass a value into a function, but not access the parameter and hope it will be used in other places. To correct this you should declare the function should look like this:

```
int taille (int * n)
{
  printf("saisie la taille de tableaux\n");
  scanf("%d\n", n);
  return 0;
}
```

Next function - similar problem, it should look like this:

```
int remplire (int n , struct empl * t ,int i)
{
  for (i=1;i<=n;i++)
  {
    printf("t[%d].nom= ",i);
    scanf("%s\n",&t[i].nom);
    printf("t[%d].prenom= ",i);
    scanf("%s\n",&t[i].pre);
    printf("t[%d].salaire= ",i);
    scanf("%f\n",&t[i].salaire);
    printf("t[%d].CIN= ",i);
    scanf("%lf\n",&t[i].cin);
  }
}
```

Or even like this:

```
int remplire (int n , int i)
```

as `t` is global variable. Also this function should return some value as it is declared to return `int`.

And now the `main` function:

```
int main()
{       
  int i,n;
  int taille(int n),
      taille(n);
  int remplire(int n,struct empl t,int i);
  remplire(n,t,i);
}
```

Don't redeclare functions inside another function, even if it is permissible it does not mean you should do it. Also main function should return 0 if everything works fine. To correct the function write it like this:

```
int main()
{       
  int i,n;
  taille(& n);
  remplire(n,& t,i);
}
```

Some good advice, please read some books to learn how to program in C if you want to go that way.

Answer (score 0):

You've declared this global array variable `t`

```
struct empl t[50];
```

and also declared a parameter `t` in this function

```
int remplire (int n , struct empl t ,int i)
```

Inside the function it's going to treat any instance of `t` as to be the parameter as that is nearer in scope than the global variable. So when you have code like this...

```
scanf("%s\n",&t[i].nom);
```

...it's going to throw up errors because `t` isn't an array.

The solution is to use variable names that have meaning like "employee_array" rather than single letters.

Also that call to `scanf` is wrong as for strings you don't need to pass in a pointer to the variable, so it should look like

```
scanf("%s\n",t[i].nom);
```

But you'd also need to make `nom` be a string too - currently it's only a char.